# handling JSON string issued by javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

The following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  [...]
if (result) {
  console.log(result)
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = result.text
let formData = new FormData();
let CodeParams = {
  code_data: result.text,
  section_id:  <%= @section.id %>
};
formData.append("code_json_data", JSON.stringify(CodeParams));
Rails.ajax({
  url: "section_update",
  type: "post",
  data: formData
});
```

is submitting

```
Parameters: {"code_json_data"=>"{\"code_data\":\"20200720T131435362700020352008405ced4b190f5c2ccc0d771e76349ff31d2d2caaabcbe0dd72ead2346a46bb7c2\",\"section_id\":19}"}
```

to a Rails controller.  However the controller  cannot parse the data:

```
@result = JSON.parse(params)  [or 'parameters']
```

returns error:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String):
```

What is the mistake here?

Comment: You're trying to parse the whole `params` hash as JSON – but what you want to do is just parse the key that actually contains the JSON, i.e. `code_json_data`. So what you need to do is: `JSON.parse(params[:code_json_data])`

Comment: RIght!  Which returns a Hash  `{"code_data"=>"20200725T131435362700020352008405ced4b190f5c2ccc0d771e76349ff31d2d2caaabcbe0dd72ead2346a46bb7c2", "section_id"=>24}`.  thus:  `@section = Section.where('id = ?', @result.with_indifferent_access['section_id']).first`

Comment: And what's the problem with this result?

Comment: None.  I left it there or someone who would eventually come across it, as parsing the data is done to access it.